# virtualbox networks breaking

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, networking, virtualbox

I have windows 7 as a host and Ubuntu 12.04 as guest. Guest has NAT connection to the outside network.

The problem is that sometimes the network in guest is breaking. It is unavailable for 5 minutes and then it is back. Sometimes I have to restart connection to fix it. Do you know, what might be the cause of the problem?

Comment: It does the same in bridged mode as well.  The only difference is that I have a Windows 7 and Ubuntu as guest to my Windows 7 Host.  Interestingly enough is that only the Ubuntu guest seems to break when both Windows and Ubuntu guests are running.

Comment: 5 minutes sounds like an IP timeout so there is something that it cannot connect to. What settings do you have on the Ubuntu VM?